# Tableau json format

Tags: json, tableau-api

In Tableau Public's documentation one can read that

> A single JSON object cannot exceed 128 MB.
>
> When a single object top-level array exceeds 128 MB, you must convert
>   it to a file where the JSON objects are defined one per line.

When trying to load a  (95 MB!) JSON file into Tableau, i get an error:

> Tableau encountered a single object larger than 128 MB in the JSON
>   file. Please try again with a smaller JSON file.

My file is one large array in the following format:

```
[
  {"id":"1389406","updatedDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","createdDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","deleted":false,"Ids":["2466958"],"location":{"code":"bibd","name":"Main Library"},"status":{"code":"-","display":"AVAILABLE"},"barcode":"blah blah","callNumber":"TS","itemType":"In-house loan"},
  {"id":"1389406","updatedDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","createdDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","deleted":false,"Ids":["2466958"],"location":{"code":"bibd","name":"Main Library"},"status":{"code":"-","display":"AVAILABLE"},"barcode":"blah blah","callNumber":"TS","itemType":"In-house loan"}
...
]
```

What could i do to make Tableau accept this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you basically have to do it as the help text stipulates. **One JSON object per line. Nothing more.** I tried just that, but I forgot to remove the comma (,) i had at the end of every line.

Your file should look like this:

```
{"id":"1389406","updatedDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","createdDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","deleted":false,"Ids":["2466958"],"location":{"code":"bibd","name":"Main Library"},"status":{"code":"-","display":"AVAILABLE"},"barcode":"blah blah","callNumber":"TS","itemType":"In-house loan"}
{"id":"1389406","updatedDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","createdDate":"2018-01-31T10:17:31Z","deleted":false,"Ids":["2466958"],"location":{"code":"bibd","name":"Main Library"},"status":{"code":"-","display":"AVAILABLE"},"barcode":"blah blah","callNumber":"TS","itemType":"In-house loan"}
```